# Backing array of an ArrayList has a different length then the ArrayList's .size()

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

While debugging an application, the following error was thrown when accessing an `ArrayList` at an invalid index:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=-1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
```

The invalid index (`-1`) was expected, but what was unexpected was the length of 5. The `ArrayList` being accessed was verified to have a `.size()` of `3`.

Digging into the source code of `ArrayList`, the following can be found:

```
/**                                            
 * Default initial capacity.                   
 */                                            
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

/**                                                                          
 * Shared empty array instance used for default sized empty instances. We    
 * distinguish this from EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA to know how much to inflate when  
 * first element is added.                                                   
 */                                                                          
private static final Object[] DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};        

/**                                                                          
 * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.     
 * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any     
 * empty ArrayList with elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA     
 * will be expanded to DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.     
 */                                                                          
// Android-note: Also accessed from java.util.Collections                    
transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access

/**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

It seems that when an `ArrayList` is instantiated, and the first item is added, the backing array by default can be given a length of `10`. This was experimentally verified (once) when the original error described above showed a length of `10`.

However, on most runs, the length of the backing array as shown in the error is `5`, while the `.size()` of the `ArrayList` being accessed remains `3`. How is this length of the backing array modified to be a length of `5`? Especially given the source code, if any value other than the value of `.size()` was shown, one would expect it to be `10`.

I would expect the internal backing array to be modified to fit the length of the number of elements inside it, especially for the purposes of throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, as the length displayed is quite confusing when it does not match the `.size()` of the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all - this is normal. `ArrayList` does this in order to be faster. If the underlying array matched the list size, add/remove operations would be much slower (requiring reallocating the array every time).

To answer your direct question, there are multiple ways to instantiate the `ArrayList` - in particular, by passing it an existing `Collection`, or by providing an `int initialCapacity`. Both of these could give you a smaller underlying array than the default.

```
// Source code of other `ArrayList` constructors below (trimmed for clarity to how `elementData` gets initialized)

public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    ...
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
    ...
}

public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    ...
    elementData = c.toArray();
    ...
}
```

Comment: And the other side is that the backing array is never automatically shrunk (though a user can use `trimToSize()` to explicitly fit the array size to the number of elements).

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal.  The `ArrayList`'s backing array, when it does get resized, is expanded to *more* than exactly the necessary size.  This is so it doesn't have to be expanded every time an element is added, because expansion requires an O(n) copy, so adding extra room reduces the number of copies you have to do.

Additionally, `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` is not actually used as the initial size.  As you might have noticed, the initial array used is actually empty, with size zero, and then the array is expanded based on how many elements are actually added.

Comment: Does the size it expands to vary between executions? I'm curious as to how lengths of `10` and `5` were observed on different runs.

Comment: It shouldn't vary like that.

Comment: @Orbit As far as I can remember, the size should double when the array is grown. This iguarantees an amortized cost for `insert` operations of "*O(log(n))*.

Comment: No, expanding by any constant multiplier >1 gives you amortized O(1) add.  O(log n) expansions will be done, though.